# Displaying a custom hierarchy

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, hierarchy

I have a simple hirachey of Tasks similar to the snipet below:

```
public class Task
{
    public Guid TaskId { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Subtasks = new List<Task>();
}
```

What would be be the best way to display this data? A TreeView would be look ideal but since im not using a DataSet is this control excluded? Or how could i modify my code to enable me to use a TreeView?

Cheers
Anthony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to make the TreeView data bound.

You can create TreeNode instances, and add them to the TreeView.Nodes collection yourself.

This would allow you to create a TreeView programmatically from your data.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [TreeView.Nodes.Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenodecollection.add.aspx).

Then use recursion to add the sub tasks. Something like this:

```
public void AddTaskToTree(TreeNodeCollection nodes, Task aTask)
{
    TreeNode taskNode = New TreeNode(aTask.Name);
    nodes.Add(taskNode);
    foreach (Task subTask in aTask.Subtasks)
    {
        AddTaskToTree(taskNode.Nodes, subTask);
    }
}
```